# Ubuntu 16.04 xrdp issue: programs do not run remotely

Tags: 16.04, remote-access, xrdp, segmentation-fault

I use Ubuntu 16.04.2. I installed xrdp and xfce4 according to [this](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952) page. It was OK and I ran some program remotely.

Then I installed some programs on the system such as CUDA 8.0, Oracle Java, openssh, vsftpd...

But now I cannot open installed program in remote session. 
For example when I run Nautilus a window appears and says:

> **Failed to execute default File Maneger.** 
>   Input/Output Error.

I tried to run nautilus via terminal but it failed and the following error massage appeared:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I also tried to run Firefox via terminal:

> $ /usr/bin/firefox 
>   ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 26648
>   ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
>   ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tried MATE desktop, but the problem recurred.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved!

As I mentioned, I have installed CUDA 8. I used CUDA `.deb` file to install it. During installation many additional package were installed. One of them was `openjdk`. After installation I removed `openjdk` and installed Oracle JDK. As a result CUDA 8 and its dependencies went to apt autoremove!

When I frustrated, I do `apt autoremove`, and magically remote session problem resolved! Then I install CUDA 8 using its `.run` file.